# Adwords search engine marketing (SEM) question

Tags: google-ads, sem

I want to promote my site using AdWords.

My site is for phone 7 application and I've just develop an application 
"fart and burp" for phone 7. So according to my guide I have use keyword tools (Google) to see what keywords to make ads for. 
I've try to search my words:

- phone 7 apps
- phone 7 app
- fart phone 7
- fart app for phone 7

All of this is for United States and UK but all words that I search return me 0 click and 0,05$ for 1 position or at the best 13-18 click for all world.

Is there a way to achieve 50 clicks a day? 
my budget is $70 just for start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what it sounds like, no you will not be able to get 50 clicks a day through the phrases you listed from Google's keyword tool. The Google Keyword Tool shows you searches per day for a given keyword phrase or set of keyword phrases.

This is what you need to look at to understand if you will get 50 clicks a day and the cost:

Clicks Per Day = Sum of all[avg # of keyword searches daily * CTR(Click Through Rate)]
Cost Per Day =  Sum of all[avg # of keyword searches daily * CTR(Click Through Rate) * CPC (Cost Per Click)]

The toughest thing to guess about is your Click Through Rate. In general I have seen Click Through rates between 0%-5%.  Usually exact keyword matches are around 3%-4% and things drop off from their.

So for your example, lets assume a 4% click through rate:

[0 Searches * .04] + [15 Searches * .04] = .6 Clicks per day
[0 Searches * .04 * $.05] + [15 Searches * .04 * $.05] = $.03 cost daily

I would suggest based off of that that you look for a much broader set of keyword phrases that match what your product does so you can get more Google ad placements and thus get some click throughs.

Comment: really thanks you know something that i can read to understand better how adword works ?:)

Comment: Here is the official AdWords Beginners Guide:

http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=21899